# How can I only search the Primary inbox in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

With the new Gmail inbox, I've gotten into the habit of ignoring everything that's not in the Primary inbox. I don't care about anything that's in any of the other inboxes (inboxen?). When I search for something, I only want to see things from my primary inbox. However, searching for something brings up results from all the inboxes. How can I only search the Primary inbox?

Comment: I wish that Gmail had made this simple. Like "in:inbox is:unread category:primary".

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Gmail now supports

```
category:primary is:unread
```

Comment: This seems correct, but it would be nice if you could link to a source for your information.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190 would seem to be the source for the information, but I don't see that it was announced anywhere.

Comment: you are the man, been looking for this for a while

Comment: this is great - TIP: bookmark the search results page -- and put it somewhere handy in your browser

Comment: That is the filer I've been looking for years :D

Answer (score 30):

The category filter now knows how to filter the "Primary" inbox, so you can use

```
in:inbox category:primary
```

Or, to show just unread messages in the "Primary inbox":

```
in:inbox category:primary is:unread
```

---

*Earlier answer:*

Doesn't look like the "category" filter knows how to filter to the "Primary" inbox, but you can do it by excluding the other categories like so:

```
in:inbox -category:(updates OR promotions OR social OR forums)
```

Or, to show just unread messages in the "Primary" inbox:

```
in:inbox -category:(updates OR promotions OR social OR forums) is:unread
```

Comment: `category:primary is:unread` as specified in the accepted answer does in fact work. Just putting it in a comment here directly since the first time I looked here, I took this as fact.

Answer (score 7):

Confirmed, as of 1-30-14,

```
is:unread category:primary
```

works.

I think I've been using `is:unread category:primary-inbox` for a while but I think they just discontinued it, because it wasn't working for me today.

Answer (score 0):

`category:primary is:unread` works better than `in:inbox -category:(updates OR promotions OR social OR forums) is:unread`. The latter, for me, excluded other unread emails from my primary inbox.

Answer (score -1):

I landed on this and what I ended up finding most useful was the source of information we are all looking for:

The GMail **Advanced Search** topic in Google's Help/Support documenation

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190

This is the most important thing to remember as in the future it will change yet again. Remember to look up *Advanced Search* in Google's help forum for the current solution.

As of April 2014 what works and is supported is:

```
is:important
```

or

```
label:important
```

an example `is:important is:unread` to clean out your primary inbox.

"Meaning: Messages [...] that were marked as important by **Priority Inbox**"

*I intend to, but of course cannot promise, I will update my answer as the solution changes. I am quite dependent on advanced search.*